# Why printing is into two lines?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, newline, urllib

one question about my code below:

```
#Python code to scrape the shipment URLs 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import urllib

# read urls of websites from text file > change it to where you stock the file
list_open = open(r"C:\***\data.csv")
#skips the header
read_list  = list_open.readlines()[1:]
file_path = "ShipmentUpdates.txt"

for url in read_list:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), "html5lib")
    # parse shipment info
    shipment = soup.find_all("span")
    Preparation = shipment[0]
    Sent = shipment[1]
    InTransit = shipment[2]
    Delivered = shipment[3]

    with open(file_path, "a") as f:
        line= f"{url} ; Preparation {Preparation.getText()}; Sent {Sent.getText()}; InTransit {InTransit.getText()}; Delivered {Delivered.getText()}"
        print (line)
        f.write(line+'\n')
```

my output is:

```
http://carmoov.fr/CfQd
 ; Preparation on 06/01/2022 at 17:45; Sent on 06/01/2022 at 18:14; InTransit ; Delivered on 07/01/2022 at 10:31
http://carmoov.fr/CfQz
 ; Preparation on 06/01/2022 at 11:18; Sent on 06/01/2022 at 18:14; InTransit ; Delivered on 07/01/2022 at 11:56
```

But I want "URL" is in the same row as shipment info.

Could you help to check what is the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: `url` contains the output of `readlines`, which does not strip newlines.  You could print `url.strip()` to remove whitespace, including newlines.

Answer (score 1):

This most likely happens because the URLs have a newline character `\n` at their end, because you read them as individual lines from `list_open`. To prevent this, replace `{url}` with `{url.strip()}` in your format-string.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `url = url.strip()`. This will removed the newline character '\n':

```
# read urls of websites from text file > change it to where you stock the file
list_open = open(r"C:\***\data.csv")
#skips the header
read_list  = list_open.readlines()[1:]
file_path = "ShipmentUpdates.txt"

for url in read_list:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), "html5lib")
    # parse shipment info
    shipment = soup.find_all("span")
    Preparation = shipment[0]
    Sent = shipment[1]
    InTransit = shipment[2]
    Delivered = shipment[3]
    url = url.strip()
    with open(file_path, "a") as f:
        line= f"{url} ; Preparation {Preparation.getText()}; Sent {Sent.getText()}; InTransit {InTransit.getText()}; Delivered {Delivered.getText()}"
        print (line)
        f.write(line+'\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer would be to use [list comprehension](https://djangostars.com/blog/list-comprehensions-and-generator-expressions/) to strip each url right as you get them:

```
list_open = open(r"C:\***\data.csv")
#skips the header
read_list = (url.strip() for url in list_open.readlines()[1:])
```

It's important to note that doing this means you can only access `read_list` **once** (which you do in you code sample), because this list comprehension creates what's called a generator (mentioned in the previous link).

If you wanted to access read_list again after your initial for-loop, you could convert it to a tuple or list by doing `read_list = tuple(url.strip() for url in list_open.readlines()[1:])` or `read_list = list(url.strip() for url in list_open.readlines()[1:])`.